# What is SkipExtraFilesOnServer? Deployment azure. ASP.NET vNext

Tags: asp.net, azure, deployment, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

I need to skip a file on the server when I deploy my app. My friend told me that I could use `SkipExtraFilesOnServer`, but I don't understand how it works.
I have a `.txt` file that I want to keep unchanged after deploy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you publish your Web App using Visual Studio, in the Publish wizard under Settings, expand the "File Publish Options" and uncheck "Remove additional files at destination".  If they are static data files your app depends on, then they should really be in the App_Data folder and you can make sure the "Exclude files from the App_Data folder" is checked.[image]. The first option leaves any unrecognized files on the destination.

In the PublishProfile under YourProject >> Properties >> PublishProfiles, you will find a copy of yourPublishProfile.pubxml.  The corresponding elements respectively in this file are:
`<SkipExtraFilesOnServer>True</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>` and `<ExcludeApp_Data>True</ExcludeApp_Data>`